# rxjs buffer until timeout reset on new arg arrivals

Tags: function, rxjs, accumulate, debouncing

Summary : I am using Rxjs and a newbie. I want to implement such a scenario, with observable, but havent had luck so far.

There is a function loadDetailsFromServer(itemIds), that calls a server api and passes some items Ids. This function is called sporadically. To optimse server calls, here is what I want to do :
with arrival of first function call, a timeout is triggered. If before the time out any new function calls arrives, timout is reset to start again. When timeout kicks in, server call is made, and argument count resets to zero.

Here is a marble-ish diagram:

```
Timer is 4 clicks.
INPUTS IN TIME        1-2---3-4-----5--------6-7--------
loadDetailsFromServer [1,2,3,4]   -      [5]         -[6,7]  

function called with [1,2,3,4] because no more calls after 4 clicks.
```

Hint: this is similar to the search Box sample and get results from server, except that interim values are of interest, and are not ignored/skipped.

Answer (score 2):

For example if you have source Observable like this:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

const TIMEOUT = 1000;

const source = Observable.range(1, 20)
    .concatMap(v => Observable.of(v).delay(Math.random() * 2000));
```

Then you can buffer its values using `scan`. To reset the buffer I'm using `.merge(bufferNotifier.mapTo(null))`. Then with `switchMap()` I always wait for 1000ms for the `forkJoin()` to emit. If it doesn't it's "overwritten" by another Observable because new buffer arrived:

```
const bufferNotifier = new Subject();

const chain = source
    .do(undefined, undefined, () => bufferNotifier.complete()) // properly complete the chain
    .merge(bufferNotifier.mapTo(null)) // reset buffer Subject
    .scan((acc, val) => {
        if (val === null) {
            return [];
        }
        acc.push(val);
        return acc;
    }, [])
    .filter(arr => arr.length > 0)
    .switchMap(buffer => { // wait 1s until emitting the buffer further
        return Observable.forkJoin(
            Observable.of(buffer),
            Observable.timer(1000).take(1),
            arr => arr
        );
    })
    .do(() => bufferNotifier.next()) // trigger reset the buffer
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

This outputs for example:

```
[ 1 ]
[ 2 ]
[ 3, 4 ]
[ 5 ]
[ 6, 7 ]
[ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
[ 13 ]
[ 14, 15 ]
[ 16 ]
[ 17 ]
[ 18 ]
[ 19, 20 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a similar `source` observable to martin's answer, something like this could work:

```
source
  .buffer(source.debounceTime(250))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

`buffer` collects all emitted values until the given observable emits. In this case, it waits until `debounceTime` emits. CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKBaZm?editors=1010